# the working directory options does not exist in scheme on Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, working-directory

When I runned the app on Xcode 15 sees my older project directory address but I don't working this directory. how can I change the working directory.

I searched for this errors but. I think the solutions for the  before versions of Xcode 15.
In Xcode 15 does not have current working directory options.

[image: the error and scheme option images]

Comment: Open the file YourApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/YourApp.xcscheme Can you find the keys `useCustomWorkingDirectory` and/or `customWorkingDirectory` in the `LaunchAction` tag? What are their values?

Comment: yes there is the  useCustomWorkingDirectory in this files

Comment: this is working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The scheme settings are stored in the file at YourApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/YourApp.xcscheme. This is an XML file, so you can directly edit the scheme information there.

Go to the `<LaunchAction>` tag, which corresponds to the "Run" tab on Xcode's "Edit Scheme" dialog. It should have the attributes `useCustomWorkingDirectory` and `customWorkingDirectory`. Set the former to "YES" and the latter to a directory you like:

```xml
<LaunchAction
    ...
    useCustomWorkingDirectory = "YES"
    customWorkingDirectory = "some/path/you/want"
    ...
>
```

Or, you can set `useCustomWorkingDirectory` to "NO" and remove `customWorkingDirectory`. This sets the working directory to the product output directory, i.e. wherever Xcode generates the output executable.